# column not allowed here .ctl and .unl file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have rodina.ctl file and rodina.unl file and when i'm trying load rodina.ctl i get:

> *Record 1: Rejected - Error on table RODINA, column DATUM_UKONCENIA. ORA-00984: column not allowed here*

in rodina.log

script:

```
Create table rodina (   
 id_rod Varchar2 (30) NOT NULL ,
 datum_ucasti Date NOT NULL ,   
 datum_ukoncenia Date, 
primary key (id_rod)  )  /
```

rodina.ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'rodina.unl'
INTO TABLE rodina
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(
  ID_ROD,
  DATUM_UCASTI "MM/DD/YYYY",
  DATUM_UKONCENIA "MM/DD/YYYY"
)
```

rodina.unl file:

```
R001/001|05/06/2017|05/10/2017|
R002/002|05/07/2017|05/07/2017|
R003/003|05/08/2017|05/08/2017|
R004/004|05/10/2017|05/11/2017|
R005/005|05/10/2017||
R006/006|05/11/2017||
R007/007|05/12/2017|05/12/2017|
R008/008|05/12/2017|05/13/2017|
R009/009|05/13/2017|05/15/2017|
R010/010|05/14/2017|05/14/2017|
R011/011|05/15/2017|05/15/2017|
R012/012|05/16/2017|05/18/2017|
R013/013|05/17/2017||
R014/014|05/18/2017|05/20/2017|
R015/015|05/20/2017|05/20/2017|
R016/016|05/21/2017||
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your control file should either [call a function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-83FF6EDC-C7F8-4F29-8994-59153BE31924.htm#SUTIL1226) to convert strings to dates:

```
DATUM_UCASTI "to_date(:DATUM_UCASTI, 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
```

or just add [the `DATE` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-79BAD970-F406-4D29-A78A-A23F63F4D360.htm):

```
DATUM_UCASTI DATE "MM/DD/YYYY"
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked with DATUM_UCASTI DATE "MM/DD/YYYY"